# Is There Something Wrong with my C# Event?

Tags: c#, events

I was trying to write an event that would write the word 'right' to the screen when it was called, but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how I could get it to work?

I tried raising the event with '+='. I then tried changing the objects to var references and that still didn't get the event to work.It still doesn't work for some reason. Here is my code:

```cs
//File: Program.cs
using PlayerMoveEvent1;
using PlayerMoveEvent2;
using PlayerMoveEvent3;
using PlayerMoveEvent4;
using PlayerMoveEvent5;
using MovementSpace;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Objects for declaring events:
        var playerMoved = new PlayerMoves();
        var moveRight = new MoveRight();
        Movement movement = new Movement();

        Console.ReadKey();
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou moved forward.");
        }
        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou moved back.");
        }
        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
        } 
        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            playerMoved.Move(movement);
            playerMoved.PlayerMoved += moveRight.OnPlayerMoved;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid movement.");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// File: MovementRight.cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using PlayerMoveEvent1;

namespace PlayerMoveEvent2
{
    public class MoveRight
    {
        
        public void OnPlayerMoved(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nRight");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// File: PlayerMove.cs
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;
using MovementSpace;

namespace PlayerMoveEvent1
{
    
    public class PlayerMoves
    {
        public delegate void PlayerMovesEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
        public event PlayerMovesEventHandler PlayerMoved;

        public void Move(Movement movement)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou moved in this direction: ");
            OnPlayerMoved();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPlayerMoved()
        {
            if (PlayerMoved != null)
            {
                PlayerMoved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] which can be executed to observe the problem, and indicate specifically what behavior you are observing vs. what behavior you are expecting and why?

Comment: If this is just for learning you might want to check out the [events programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/).

Answer (score 1):

You must subscribe to the event with `+=` before the event is triggered.

```cs
var playerMoved = new PlayerMoves();
var moveRight = new MoveRight();
var moveLeft = new MoveLeft();
playerMoved.PlayerMoved += moveRight.OnPlayerMoved;
playerMoved.PlayerMoved += moveLeft.OnPlayerMoved;
// Now, the moveRight and moveLeft objects have subscribed to the `PlayerMoved` event.
// Do this += once for each subscriber!

...

// This raises the event and calls moveRight.OnPlayerMoved and moveLeft.OnPlayerMoved:
playerMoved.Move(movement);
```

The problem with this design is that `OnPlayerMoved` will be called for all the movement types who subscribed the event. I see 2 possibilities to fix this problem:

1. Pass the movement type to the `PlayerMovesEventHandler` delegate through a class derived from `EventArgs`.
2. Declare separate events for each movement type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribing to the event inside the Main method, you should handle the subscription in the constructor or an initialization method. Subscribing to an event multiple times won't work correctly, and subscribing to the event inside a conditional block might not be what you want.

Reading the console key multiple times in the if conditions might cause unexpected behavior. It's better to read the key once and store it in a variable to use it in multiple conditions.

Updated code below:

```cs
using System;

namespace PlayerMoveEvent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Objects for declaring events:
            var playerMoved = new PlayerMoves();
            var moveRight = new MoveRight();
            Movement movement = new Movement();

            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou moved forward.");
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou moved back.");
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                // Handle left movement
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                playerMoved.Move(movement);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid movement.");
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
            }

            // Subscribe to the event after handling the movement
            playerMoved.PlayerMoved += moveRight.OnPlayerMoved;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    // MoveRight class remains unchanged

    // PlayerMoves class remains unchanged
}
```